# How to develop multiplayer game using Bluetooth

Tags: android, multiplayer, 2d-games

Really I am new in game development. I have not any idea how to design the games for Android with Multiplayers. I searched a lot for that but did not get good tutorials. Kindly any expert suggest to me below things:

1) How to develop games in Android? Which basic level languages should i need to learn?

2) How to configure it in MultiPlayers game? Which one is best TCP or UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think you should use Unity3D engine. For this there a some helpful tutorials avaiable.
[Tutorials for Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials)

2) I think bluethooth isnt't the best nowadays for gaming because everybody got Internet and if you implement bluethooth Gamers have to stay near together.

For bluethooth this might help you:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500502/android-multiplayer-bluetooth)

If you want to use the Google Play Interface here is a tutorial (in my opinion the best way nowadays):
[here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer)

Comment: Thanks for your kindly suggestion.